# Not visible in render view

Tags: mesh

I have simple mesh and its visible in solid view. But when click on render view its disappear.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't see any lights in your scene, maybe that could be the issue?

Comment: Try replacing hdr with another one

Comment: mesh has its own light (emission) to it

Comment: Well I downloaded the blender file and the mesh shows up just fine for me, you didn't pack the HDRi you ware using so I can't tell if that was an issue. Also I'm using Blender 2.81 while you choose to use 2.79 I assume (I assume you have your reasons)